# Putting dygraph-combined.js on a diet

Tags: javascript, github, dygraphs

I'm a super noob with GitHub so chances are good that I'm missing something very basic.  I've forked the dygraphs repository and now I want to re-compile it to take up less space because I want to code it into a microprocessor as a stand-alone offline browser based logger graphing tool.

I thought that I could just comment the unwanted js files out in dygraph-dev.js and compile a new combined js to get a leaner version.  BUT that doesn't seem to do anything as a file-comparison of the original and new dygraph-combined.js states that the files are identical.

Help?

PS:
I'm using GitHub in Windows 7 with Cygwin installed and I compile using code:
    sh generate-combined.sh
inside my local dygraphs directory

Answer (score 0):

*dygraph-dev.js* is just used to include all dygraph files in a website. What you want is to modify the [generate-combined.sh](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/master/generate-combined.sh#L8) file and remove files from `GetSources` (start at line 8).